# Deploy Node.js server on Dreamhost

Tags: node.js, deployment, dreamhost

I am going to deploy Typescript(React) app on the Dreamhost.
But I don't know how to do that.
I can connect by SSH to the server.
`Should I install npm by SSH then run that?`
I saw an option about passenger on the Dreamhost server.
If I select this check box, then message shows *requires VPS or dedicated server running a recent OS version*.

But I don't know at all about how to do this. I have been using Dreamhost for only few months.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What requires a VPS or Dedicated server, is the RVM module:

[image: Passenger setting on Dreamhost]

Regarding your question: Node.js is not installed by default on newer DreamHost servers. You must manually install a custom version under your server's username.
Once installed, npm is also installed and you'll be able to run the commands below.

View the following article for instructions on how to install a custom version of Node.js.

[Installing a custom version of NVM and Node.js](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029083351-Installing-a-custom-version-of-NVM-and-Node-js)

Comment: Thank you, @kilinkis.
I have solved this before as you described here.